# How to set a symbol instance name on many keyframes

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I have some timeline based animation. Some symbol is sitting on its layer on many keyframes and has no instance name. Now i want to give it an instance name.

Is there a way to achieve it without passing on every keyframe and manually setting symbol's name?

PS: Using of "Edit multiple frames" somehow doesn't helps , instance name field simply disappears:
[image]

Comment: look all layers except the instance you're interested, use Edit multiple frames and ctrl/CMD +A (select all), then setting the instance name should work

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza tried exactly this way and all similar ways. it is simply blocking the option to set instance name , look: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uZI5C.png

Comment: are you sure there is only one instance on that layer ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza yes , already checked this direction , it is one and only. removed everything else on the stage , minimized keyframes count to 2 - nothing helpes. Found this but this is not exactly what i need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410011/setting-instance-names-on-keyframes-quickly-in-as3

Comment: I was thinking of brute force JSFL as well. Do you mind sharing a cs5.5 .fla ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [this extension](http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2010/03/30/set-instance-name-on-multiple-frames/)?

Comment: it works! even more, now i know what is this "Commands" button up there :)

Comment: You might also like these others http://flashspeaksactionscript.com/20-ways-extend-flash-workspace/